# MySQL match().... against() with numbers

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, match

This [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-boolean.html) explains about the `match()... against()` feature to search the texts within any columns from a database table. Is it possible to use same feature to search all fields in a table based on the columns type `number` which contains different ids something like,

**EDIT:**

I have a table like this:

```
name        column1 column2 
----------- ------- ------- 
fifth user  50      35      
fourth user 51      30      
third user  52      31      
second user 53      31      
First User  54      35
```

Now I want to get all names which contains the numbers 31 and 51 in any one of columns `column1` and `column2` which are of type number.

So, I tried with,

```
SELECT name FROM table_name WHERE MATCH (column1, column2) AGAINST ('31 51' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

But didn't worked.

Comment: What is the `ft_min_word_len` value ? you can check it by `show variables like 'ft_%';`

Comment: @Abhik - `ft_min_word_len` value is 4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't fully understand your syntax.  A column can only contain one number.  You can do this:

```
where someNumber1 in (column1, column3) or
      someNumber2 in (column1, column3)
```

What more do you want?

Comment: @mpsbhat . . . I changed the `and` to an `or`, which seems to do what you want.

Comment: Its enough for few rows. But in my case, there are 10k+ rows & more than 10 numbers to consider which are getting dynamically based on some other conditions. So the query become long in length like `where someNumber1 in (column1, column3) or someNumber2 in (column1, column3) or someNumber3 in (column1, column3) or someNumber4 in (column1, column3) or someNumber5 in (column1, column3)`.That's why I like to find something like in question which is becoming easier something like `where (someNumber1 or someNumber2) in (column1, column3)` since `in (column1, column3)` is same for all n someNumbers.

Answer (score 0):

Your `ft_min_word_len value` is 4 meaning the searched word length must be at-least of length 4 for full text search to happen, and below that length it will return no result.

You may need to reset the length to 2 and this is how you can do it

In debian/ubuntu OS you can change the value of `ft_min_word_len` by updating the `my.cnf` file The location of the file is usually under

`/etc/mysql`

So go to the above folder and type

```
sudo vi my.cnf
```

Then in the file check for the block `[mysqld]` and see if the variable is already there if not then just add the line

```
ft_min_word_len = 2
```

Save it and and restart mysql

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql restart
```

or

```
sudo service mysql restart
```

If you already had the full text indexes on a table before doing the above operation, after above changes drop the indexes and rebuilt or you can do a repair the table from mysql terminal something as

```
repair table table_name quick
```

Comment: is it possible to add fulltext indexes for the column type `INT`?

Comment: Good question I did not notice the first part that you have mentioned into the question. Well for integer column full text search does not make sense. Since an interger can hold one value not multiple. But a text field can have a complete sentence `mysql is a good relational database`. So if you want to do a search or `relational` matching the field then full text search is the option for you in many ways. So yes for integer fields though its not mentioned anywhere in the doc and honestly I have never tried on int datatype, you can try and see if it works. But its meant for text fields.

Comment: I have tried. But unable to add full text index to the column type `INT`

Comment: So yes its limited to the `text` `varchar` datatypes